How to plot GARCH model volatility against the time series data?
I am a beginner at R Code and Econometrics. Currently I have created a threshold GARCH model for forecasting volatility of asset prices. I am having a hard time understanding how to plot two charts on top of each other trying to compare volatility against actual time series, or even using that to see how the model performs with actual data.
spec.tgarch <- ugarchspec(variance.model = list(model = "fGARCH",
                                                submodel = "TGARCH",
                                               garchOrder = c(1,1)),
                         mean.model = list(armaOrder=c(1,0)))
tGarchModel <- ugarchfit(spec.tgarch, data=dl_data)
tGarchModel

vol <- ts(tGarchModel@fit$sigma^2,end = c(2024,1), frequency = 12)
plot(vol, xlab="", ylab="", main="Threshold GARCH Volatility")

plot(ts_data, type = "l", col = "blue", ylab = "Price", xlab = "Time", main = "Comparison of Actual Volatility vs Model Predicted Volatility")
lines(vol, col = "red")

# Add a legend
legend("topright", legend = c("Actual Volatility", "Model Predicted Volatility"), col = c("blue", "red"), lty = 1)

Yet what I manage to do is having only the time series data added to the plot (blue) and no red line appears. Also, the legend appears too.

What's the relationship between dl_data and ts_data? I assume that the former is your returns time series. It's not clear where the latter comes from.

@datawookie ts_data - time series data, dl_data = diff(log(ts_data)

Thanks. I suggest adding that to the code in your question please.

I'm not completely sure what you are wanting to plot, but assuming that you want to see the returns with the modeled volatility overland, perhaps something like this?
spec.tgarch <- ugarchspec(
  variance.model = list(
    model = "fGARCH",
    submodel = "TGARCH",
    garchOrder = c(1,1)
  ),
  mean.model = list(armaOrder=c(1,0))
)
tGarchModel <- ugarchfit(spec.tgarch, data=dl_data)
tGarchModel

plt <- plot(
  dl_data,
  col = "darkgrey",
  xlab="",
  ylab="",
  main="Threshold GARCH Volatility",
  grid.col = "lightgrey"
)
plt <- addSeries(sigma(tGarchModel), col = "red", on = 1)
plt <- addSeries(-sigma(tGarchModel), col = "red", on = 1)
plt



Yes indeed, it's probably what I've wanted to achieve. So far closest answer to the question.

Encoutering an error:
Error in get(".xts_chob", .plotxtsEnv) : object '.xts_chob' not found

You're going to need to provide more context please. Please try your code in a fresh R session. If the error persists then please add your current code to the question so that I can reproduce the error. FWIW I'm not getting this error running just the code I provided in a fresh R session.
